# coordinates responded by marker after dragged was incorrect

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://demo.chan15.info/map/

This is my demo page, it will response the coordinates after marker dragged, but I found if you drag to some place the coordinates will be wrong very often, especially nearby the river, but if use real google map website and click any place on the river, you will get the correct coordinates, and if you draw the map by the coordinates from google map website it will be correct, How to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code directly in question. External links tends to be broken at some point, so the question doesn't make sense for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue in your code is in the following piece

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: marker.getPosition()
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var responseAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                var locations = results[0].geometry.location;

                lat.value = locations.lat();
                lng.value = locations.lng();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Once you finished dragging a marker you execute a reverse geocoding and get coordinates from results of reverse geocoding. Please note that reverse geocoding generally won't return a position of your marker, it will return the nearest known address position.

To illustrate this have a look at the Geocoder tool and how it resolves coordinate   `25.082015,121.501121` that is close to river

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D25.082015%252C121.501121

[image]

As you can see the coordinate `25.082015,121.501121` is resolved to the nearest address (marker A on the road) with coordinates `25.081415,121.499519`. So when you draw a second map it uses coordinates of resolved address instead of coordinates of your marker.

In order to solve this and have coordinates of your marker change your code to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    lat.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    lng.value = marker.getPosition().lng();
});
```

You don't need reverse geocoding at all. I hope this helps!